# Thread safety in python metaclass's __call__, __new__ and __init__ methods

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety

From my understanding, the `__new__` and `__init__` methods of a python metaclass, are called when creating the *class object* of the class that declared the metaclass. Therefore, these methods would be called only once for each distinct class (FQN). Is this understanding correct?

Are these invocations of `__new__` and `__init__` thread safe? Is it because of the GIL or some other mechanism in the interpreter that ensures that only one thread can call the `__new__` and/or `__init__` methods of metaclass (for the same class object - or FQN?).

I'm a bit new to python and my understanding of the *magic* that python does below the hood is fairly limited - having said that - for every fully qualified class name, I think there should only be one class object in memory. So how does python guarantee this when a metaclass is being invoked during the class object creation process in a multi-threaded scenario?